# remove query in mongodb by _id with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

removing a row in mongodb isn't seem to be that easy as in SQL lol, well, my issue is that I cant remove a row by the _id because the _id contains an obj `ObjectId`, that's the row in the db,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("541ec60e41b46b841adde31e"),
    "name" : "TT"
}
```

and this is how I'm trying to remove it,

```
db.books.remove({ _id: book_id}, function(err, delete) {
    if(err)
        console.log("ERROR!", err);

    console.log("deleted  ", delete);
});
```

I've no idea how to pass the `book_id` so the query will run as expected,
hope you guys will be able to help me find a solution for this one.
thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert `book_id` to an `ObjectId` first:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

...

db.books.remove({ _id: ObjectId(book_id) }, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var {MongoClient,ObjectID} = require('mongodb');


var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if(err!=null){
        return console.log(err.message)
    }
  db.collection("App").deleteOne({_id:ObjectID('59c3dfa6d11caa3360af91cc')}, function (err,data) {

       if(err!=null){
            return console.log(err)
        }
        console.log(data);

    });

});
```